# Ordinal logistic regression with aggregated data

Tags: count-data, ordered-logit, aggregation

I'm wondering if it is feasible to conduct a ordinal logistic regression on the following dataset.

I want to investigate if there is a correlation between the alcohol outlet density (as counts) and the city (in)compatibility (on a ordinal scale).

I have 27 region units of a 500m radius wherein I have counted the different alcohol oulets (count data). Besides this I have the assessement regarding the city (in)compatibility on a ordinal scale (very, rather (in)compatible; four gradations) for every 27 units.

I would control this relationship for neighborhood characteristics in the 27 regions.
The different codes stand for different alcohol outlet types (e.g. 563001 = Bars / 563002 = restaurants etc.)[image]